# How to fade fixed elements when page scrolls, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade

On a page with a fixed element, like a corner ad or a notice, I'd like that element to fade once the page scrolls down a certain amount.

To start off, what would be the best way to determine when: pixels, percentage, other?
Finally, how would I achieve this effect using jQuery?

Comment: Please make some attempt to research/implement this yourself.  Then once you have done so, if you are having specific issues, come back and ask a more specific question, ideally with some non-working code involved.

Comment: I did. My issue arose when I tried doing it with a fixed element. To be blunt and sincere: It's a simple problem, sure, but I also have very little time. I didn't just shoot here and ask without any attempts or Google'ing. Please make some attempt to not jump to conclusions.

Comment: I did not jump to any conclusions.  Whether or not you tried something makes no difference if it is not included in your question.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist  See the 2nd bullet point.  If you have already tried something and it did not work, that should be included in your question.  Including actual code if it exists is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code segment to get scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var pos = $('body').scrollTop();
    if(pos > 500) {
         //fade in your element
    } else {
         //fade out your element or whatever
    }
});
```

You can `fadeIn()` elements when scrolling to this position...